# Rust Documentation Test unresolved name

Tags: rust

I wanted to add documentation tests to my code, but I can't seem to get a very basic example working.  Here is what I have:

````
/// Foo function inside foo.rs
///
/// # Examples
///
/// ```
/// foo();
/// ```
fn foo() {
}
````

The error I get is:

> <anon>:2:5: 2:8 error: unresolved name `foo` [E0425]

I also have a lib.rs but its only contents are:

```
// Contents of lib.rs
pub mod foo;
```

Comment: This worked for me. I added fn main(){} before it though. rustc --version? Are you running rustdoc foo.rs?

Comment: rustc version is 1.6.0.  I'm not running rustdoc, just "cargo test"

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out.  I added the following line to lib.rs:

```
pub use self::foo::foo
```

Then I modified foo.rs to:

````
/// Foo function inside foo.rs
///
/// # Examples
///
/// ```
/// use foo::foo;
/// foo();
/// ```
fn foo() {
}
````

After doing so, the documentation test ran successfully.

Comment: I'd like to add that you can start lines in example code with `///#` so they are omitted in the docs.

Comment: `fn foo()` is private, yet with `pub use self::foo::foo` you are [publicly re-exporting it](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/visibility-and-privacy.html#re-exporting-and-visibility). This may be an unintended side-effect.